# Mysql aruba Json type dosen't exist

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I bought a  linux hosting with mysql from aruba.it to deploy on it my personal work (php - codeigniter -mysql ). I developped it in my local machine and I used a mysql version 5.7.14 .In this version there is a type Json and a use it for different operation. In aruba mysql this type dosn't exist, I think that mysql version is old. Please can you suggest me what kind of type i will use to store json in this db?

Answer (score 1):

Store it as type text, you won't be able to do anything fancy from within the database with it, but MySQL's not really made for processing JSON anyway. As type text SQL will just see it as any other string, and you'll have to do any processing from within your application.